# I need complete tutorial about MSSQL 2008 Database mirroring for load balancing

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, load-balancing, mirroring

I need complete tutorial about MSSQL 2008 Database mirroring for load balancing

i want to load balance my SQL workload

all database insert update and delete queries will be mirrored

all select queries will be load balanced

sql servers will run at windows server 2008r2 at different computers (VPS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replication may be an option for you: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500346.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Database mirroring *is not* load balancing: it's high availability.

You can not load balance SELECT queries.

What you *can* do it create database snapshots of the mirror and then use this for reporting. However, the snapshot is fixed in time and does not receive any updates.

What kind of volumes do you have that you think this will help? Normally stuffing more RAM into a 64 bit installation works a treat.